# Why does my C code keep returning 0's in the command prompt?

Tags: c, char, command-prompt

Upper case letters are supposed to become lowercase, lowercase to uppercase, numbers are incremented by 1, and 9 becomes 0. When standard input is included, my code works, but the command line keeps returning 0 every time I press enter

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=2132;i++)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if(c>='a' && c<='z')
        {
            c-=32;
        }
        else if(c>='A' && c<='Z')
        {
            c+=32;
        }
        else if(c>='0' && c<'9')
        {
            c++;
        }

        else if(c='9')
        {
            c-=9;
        }
    putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c='9'` sets c to '9'

Comment: You are using assignment equals, not "equals-equals" as required. `c == 9` checks if `c` is equal to 9. This is a common mistake when determining equality.

Comment: mind that you can use literals to make your code clearer, eg: `c - 'a' + 'A'`

Comment: Regarding: `c = getchar();`  The function `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: In the future, the current `c=9` error can be avoided by placing the literal on the left hand side, then the compiler would complain of you accidentally used `=` rather than `==`

Comment: read compiler warnings and it'll tell you the error right away

Answer (score 2):

The mistake happened in line `else if(c='9')`.

Notice that in all the other cases you are using comparison, whereas here you are assigning `c` to `'9'`. The difference is that you used `=` instead of `==`, and hence if `c` is *digit* nine, all four if/else if statements evaluate to false.

Use `(c == '9')` to check if character `c` is equal to digit nine.